# Timeout Error: You have uncommitted work pending when Queueable is being called from trigger

Tags: apex, callout, queueable-apex

I have a class with `@future` method:

```
public without sharing class SubmitOnApproval {
    @future 
    public static void oppRecordsToSubmit(id oppId){        
            Opportunity o = [select id, recordtype.DeveloperName from Opportunity where id = : oppId];
            if(o.recordtype.DeveloperName!='PIP_Finished_Product'){
                List<GT_Quote__c> oppQuote = new List<GT_Quote__c>();
                oppQuote = [Select id, opportunity__c, Submit_Request_Picklist__c, Product__c
                              from GT_Quote__c
                              where opportunity__c = :oppId 
                              and Submit_Request_Picklist__c = 'Draft'
                              and Product__c != ''
                              and Quote_Stage__c = 'Request Pending'];

                if(oppQuote.size()>0){            
                    for(GT_Quote__c quote : oppQuote){
                        quote.Submit_Request_Picklist__c = 'Submit';
                    }   
                    database.update(oppQuote, True);
                }
            }                          
        }
    }
```

When the update happens my `QuoteAfterUpdate` trigger is called which creates a list of quotes to send to a web service. I am using Queueable apex:

```
trigger QuoteAfterUpdate on GT_Quote__c (after update) {   
    List<Id> quoteToBeSendId = new List<Id>();  
    for(GT_Quote__c quote : trigger.new){
            List<String> recordTypesAllowed = new List<String>{'FERT', 'HAWA', 'ROH', 'VERP'};
            if(Trigger.oldMap.get(quote.Id).Quote_Name__c == null && Trigger.newMap.get(quote.Id).Quote_Name__c != null && Trigger.newMap.get(quote.Id).Submit_Request_Picklist__c == 'Submit' && (recordTypesAllowed.contains(Trigger.newMap.get(quote.Id).ProductType__c))){
                    quoteToBeSendId.add(quote.Id);
                    system.debug('Quote ID -> ' + quote.Id);
            }
            else if(Trigger.newMap.get(quote.Id).Submit_Request_Picklist__c == 'Submit' && Trigger.oldMap.get(quote.Id).Submit_Request_Picklist__c != 'Submit' && (recordTypesAllowed.contains(Trigger.newMap.get(quote.Id).ProductType__c))) {
                quoteToBeSendId.add(quote.Id);
            }
        }   

    if(!quoteToBeSendId.isEmpty()){
        QuoteRestCallouts sendToVendavo = new QuoteRestCallouts(quoteToBeSendId);
        ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(sendToVendavo);  
    }
}
```

My `QuoteRestCallouts` class is below:

```
public class QuoteRestCallouts implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    private List<Id> quoteRecordIdList = new List<Id>();
    private List<GT_Quote__c> quotesToUse = new List<GT_Quote__c>();

    public QuoteRestCallouts(List<Id> quoteIdList) {
        this.quoteRecordIdList = quoteIdList;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        for (Id quoteId : quoteRecordIdList) {
            GT_Quote__c q = [SELECT Id, 
                        Name,
                        //GET MORE FIELDS HERE
                        FROM GT_Quote__c WHERE id=:quoteId];

                        quotesToUse.add(q);
        }

        for (GT_Quote__c q : quotesToUse) {
            HttpRequest request = generateHttpRequest(generateRequestBody(q));

            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse res;

            try {
                res = http.send(request);

                if (res.getStatusCode() < 200 || res.getStatusCode() > 300) {

                    showFullResponse();

                    createErrorMessageAndSendEmail();

                } else {
                    showFullResponse();
                }
            }
            catch (System.CalloutException e) {
                createErrorMessageAndSendEmail();  
            }
        }   
    }
```

When it is the `SubmitOnApproval` class which triggers the `QuoteAfterUpdate` trigger I receive the below error:

```
Timeout Error: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
```

When I trigger the `QuoteAfterUpdate` trigger just by creating multiple quotes the callout works and both are sent to the web service.

I believe I receive the error because in `SubmitOnApproval` there is `database.update(oppQuote, True);` which is a DML statement before the callout in the same transaction but I'm not sure how to get around this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried making your method `oppRecordsToSubmit` with `@future(callout = true)`?

Comment: Thanks but I just tried but received the same error

Comment: are you getting error in unittest?

Comment: Not currently. My unit test is only testing `QuoteRestCallout` that has been called from trigger. It isn't testing for when it is called from trigger that has been triggered by `SubmitOnApproval`

Comment: @LukeBray Try to put the HTTP callout code `HttpRequest request = generateHttpRequest(generateRequestBody(q));` to a different future method with marking `callout` attribute to true. This way transaction might get completed, I'm not sure though.

Comment: by definition, the queueable execute runs in its own transaction (except in a unit testmethod); note `createErrorMessageAndSendEmail()` is in a loop of callouts and if this method does DML, and loop is 2+ iterations; you will get this error

Comment: @cropedy Thanks, this seems to be the issue. When I commented out that method it worked. I guess because it is creating an email message it is doing a DML operation. If you would like to add as an answer I will accept as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments I solved this issue be moving the creation of my email message outside my `for` loop. Creating a `SingleEmailMessage` must do a DML operation and I think this is what was causing my issue.

I am now creating the email body within the `for` loop as a string and creating the email message and sending it outside the loop.